# How to automate stopping a program at bootup, not removing it from bootup

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, script

Okay folks I want your help to be a bad, but only a little bad!

My work has an annoying program that displays which machine I'm running on, so as not to confuse different type's of computers.  I know why it's there and the intent, but frankly it's annoying and I don't feel I need it, I already know which window is which.  Since there is no guidance technically saying I have to keep it up, and it gets in the way of my work, I usually open up task manager and disable it as soon as I log in.

I'd like to automate this, to have my bootup process disable the task directly.  Let me be clear I'm not asking how to remove this from my startup only how to kill it once it starts up.  In fact this program is not in my startup so I don't know where they stuck the hooks in to make it run; and even if I did know I don't want to remove them.  What I want is to allow it to startup as normal on the machine, but when my personal account logs in to the vm it should then run a second script that then kills the program.

This would be a simple line in bashrc on linux, but I don't know windows.  How do I automate killing it in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct permissions, your scheduled task set up, this is a very simple solution (in cmd.exe / batch script):

```
rem wait for the program to come online
rem simplest solution is to "sleep"
timeout /t 15

rem kill the process
taskkill /im YourProcessName.exe /f
```

Comment: had to make it a .bat file not a .exe, but it seems to work.  Waiting until tomorrow to see if it works on reboot, if so I'll accept this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mention this is on a VM.
That probably means you have only limited rights (no admin) in the remote session so your only way to automate something is using the Task Scheduler (if that isn't disabled either) with a task triggered on "log in". (GChuf already explained how to do that.)
But this is only going to work if you have persistent sessions between VM logins. If you get a fresh user-profile on each login the Scheduled Task won't "stick" and you can't automate this at all.

If yo can't have any schedule either, but you do have access to a personal network-share or OneDrive in the VM you could put the script there and just run it when needed. (May be a little quicker/easier than going through Task Manager every time.)